# How to change input qubits (q3 and q4) in 5qubit quantum circuit

Tags: qiskit

Working on a quantum using `qiskit`. I would want to change the input qubit `q4, q3` while measuring the output `q2, q1` and record the probabilities of possible outcome as far attached [image: figure].

**Question:** How do I change the input in `qiskit`? Already created quantum registers and  added all qubits (also attached) [image: here].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Qiskit, each qubit starts off in the ground state (0 state). So, if by change the input you mean change the starting value from 0 to 1, the only way to do that would be to apply an X-Gate to qubits q3 and q4. This gate acts similar to a classical NOT gate, so it can be used to flip a qubit from 0 to 1 or vice-versa.

Looking at the table in 5(a), they want you to go through all 4 possible inputs for q3 and q4 (00, 01, 10, 11). So for each of these inputs, your X-Gate assignments would be as follows:

Input 00: No X-Gates needed
Input 01: X-Gate on q3
Input 10: X-Gate on q4
Input 11: X-Gate on q3 and q4

Answer (score 0):

There is also the `QuantumCircuit.initialize` function, which can either set individual qubits:

```
from math import sqrt

from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile
from qiskit_aer import Aer, AerSimulator
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram

# Full sate vector.

qc = QuantumCircuit(2, 2)
qc.initialize([1/sqrt(2), 0, 0, 1j/sqrt(2)])
print(qc)
print(Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator').run(qc, shots=1).result().get_statevector())
qc.cx(0, 1)
print(qc)
print(Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator').run(qc, shots=1).result().get_statevector())
print()

# Individual qubits

qc = QuantumCircuit(2, 2)
qc.initialize(0, 0)
print(qc)
print(Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator').run(qc, shots=1).result().get_statevector())
qc.cx(0, 1)
print(qc)
print(Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator').run(qc, shots=1).result().get_statevector())
print()

qc = QuantumCircuit(2, 2)
qc.initialize(1, 0)
print(qc)
print(Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator').run(qc, shots=1).result().get_statevector())
qc.cx(0, 1)
print(qc)
print(Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator').run(qc, shots=1).result().get_statevector())
print()
```

Output:

```
     ┌───────────────────────────────────┐
q_0: ┤0                                  ├
     │  Initialize(0.70711,0,0,0.70711j) │
q_1: ┤1                                  ├
     └───────────────────────────────────┘
c: 2/═════════════════════════════════════
                                          
Statevector([0.70710678+0.j        , 0.        +0.j        ,
             0.        +0.j        , 0.        +0.70710678j],
            dims=(2, 2))
     ┌───────────────────────────────────┐     
q_0: ┤0                                  ├──■──
     │  Initialize(0.70711,0,0,0.70711j) │┌─┴─┐
q_1: ┤1                                  ├┤ X ├
     └───────────────────────────────────┘└───┘
c: 2/══════════════════════════════════════════
                                               
Statevector([0.70710678+0.j        , 0.        +0.70710678j,
             0.        +0.j        , 0.        +0.j        ],
            dims=(2, 2))

     ┌───────────────┐
q_0: ┤ Initialize(0) ├
     └───────────────┘
q_1: ─────────────────
                      
c: 2/═════════════════
                      
Statevector([1.+0.j, 0.+0.j, 0.+0.j, 0.+0.j],
            dims=(2, 2))
     ┌───────────────┐     
q_0: ┤ Initialize(0) ├──■──
     └───────────────┘┌─┴─┐
q_1: ─────────────────┤ X ├
                      └───┘
c: 2/══════════════════════
                           
Statevector([1.+0.j, 0.+0.j, 0.+0.j, 0.+0.j],
            dims=(2, 2))

     ┌───────────────┐
q_0: ┤ Initialize(1) ├
     └───────────────┘
q_1: ─────────────────
                      
c: 2/═════════════════
                      
Statevector([0.+0.j, 1.+0.j, 0.+0.j, 0.+0.j],
            dims=(2, 2))
     ┌───────────────┐     
q_0: ┤ Initialize(1) ├──■──
     └───────────────┘┌─┴─┐
q_1: ─────────────────┤ X ├
                      └───┘
c: 2/══════════════════════
                           
Statevector([0.+0.j, 0.+0.j, 0.+0.j, 1.+0.j],
            dims=(2, 2))
```

https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/13202/qiskit-initializing-n-qubits-with-binary-values-0s-and-1s also discusses how to initialize all qubits to either 0 or 1 without an exponential number of entries.

Tested on:

```
qiskit==0.45.1
qiskit-aer==0.12.2
```